# Openlayer2: Can I add more circles on layer without removing last ones?

Tags: gis, openlayers

I have a simple openlayer programm to add circle on mouse click. But for new circle it will remove last ones.I am giving jsfiddel link. kindly update it if you can help. further code is also here .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.16.0/css/ol.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
   $(window).load(function() {
       function updateIcon(f) {
          
           vector.drawFeature(f);
       }
 
       options = {
           div: "map",
           zoom: 2,
           center: [0, 0],
           layers: [
               new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM()
           ]
       };
       map = new OpenLayers.Map(options);
       vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector();
       map.addLayer(vector);
 
       var point1 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(0, 0);
       var point2 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(5000000, 1000000);
       var point3 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(2000000, 2000000);
       var radius = $("#amount").val();
       var mycircle = OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon(point2, radius, 20, 0);
       var featurecircle = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(mycircle);
 
 
       ///vector.addFeatures([featurecircle]);
 

 
       OpenLayers.Control.Click = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {
           defaultHandlerOptions: {
               'single': true,
               'double': false,
               'pixelTolerance': 0,
               'stopSingle': false,
               'stopDouble': false
           },
 
           initialize: function(options) {
               this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, this.defaultHandlerOptions);
               OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(
                   this, arguments
               );
               this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(
                   this, {
                       'click': this.trigger
                   }, this.handlerOptions
               );
           },
 
           trigger: function(e) {
               console.log(map)
               console.log(e)
               var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
               var newPoint = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonlat.lon, lonlat.lat);
               vector.removeFeatures([featurecircle]);
               var mycircle = OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon(
                   newPoint,
                   radius,
                   40,
                   0
               );
            
               featurecircle = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(mycircle);
               vector.addFeatures([featurecircle]);
           }
 
       });
      
       var click = new OpenLayers.Control.Click();
       map.addControl(click);
       click.activate();
 
   }); //]]>
    </script>
</head>
 
<body>
    <p>
        
        <input type="text" id="amount" value="1000000" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
    </p>
    <div id="slider-range-max"></div>
    <div id="map" style="width:600px;height:600px;"></div>
</body>
 
</html>
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/zLjae81b/30/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you want to remove while removing it yourself?

Just remove the removing code (line 108):

```
vector.removeFeatures([featurecircle]);
```

Comment: well Yes I got it 4 days ago :p . Well still thank you and accepting answer.